# How can I make semi-log graph in Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-plot

I'd like to make semi-log graph to show my amplitude spectrum data by using Core Plot in my iOS App.
But I couldn't find how to make it.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the scale type on the plot space:

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xScaleType = CPTScaleTypeLinear; // this is the default
plotSpace.yScaleType = CPTScaleTypeLog;
```

You can see samples in the example apps provided with Core Plot. The axis demo in the Mac CPTTestApp uses a log axis and the Plot Gallery app has examples as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I drew y=exp(x) and set `plotSpace.yScaleType = CPTScaleTypeLog` for test, and got really weird result.
[result image](http://i53.tinypic.com/2v360p5.png)
Could you tell me what's going on?

Comment: There's not enough in that image to tell what's happening. Can you post your plot space setup and datasource code?

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/DvfMTidJ)'s my code. I wrote it in my ViewController. Thanks.

Comment: Plot ranges with a log scale can't include zero or negative numbers. Try using a y location of 0.1 instead of -1.